# rm -f file と rm file || true に差はある？

Tags: bash, shellscript, sh

bash で `file` という名前のファイルを削除したいが、そのファイルが存在しなかったときも終了ステータスを `0` にしたいと思い、`rm -f file` を使いました。しばらくして、とある方が同じ目的で `rm file || true` を使っていることを知りました。私の環境ではどちらの場合もスクリプト実行後の `$?` が `0` になってくれたのですが、それ以外の違いがあるのか、`man` を見てもよく分かりませんでした。

質問: `rm -f file` と `rm file || true` の挙動に何か違いはありますか？ 特定の環境における差でも構いません。

私の環境: bash 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), rm (GNU coreutils) 8.25

Comment: 確かに [GNU coreutils のマニュアル](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_coreutils/man1/rm.1.html)は解り難いですね。特に「確認も行わない」というのが「存在しないファイルを無視する」場合の話だと誤解されそうです。[Open Group の記述](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) の方が網羅的で誤解がないかも知れません。

Comment: @mjy POSIX 版のマニュアルが公開されていたのですね！　GNU coreutils はほぼ POSIX 互換のはずなので、そちらのマニュアルを見てもよいということですね。なるほど、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rm file || true`だと、そのファイルを消すか尋ねられますが、`rm -f file`だと尋ねられません。`-f`はnever promptなので。
前者が尋ねられるかどうかは環境によるかもしれませんが.

Answer (score 6):

`file` が無いとき
- `rm -f file` は無言で終了し終了コード 0
- `rm file || true` は「ファイルがありません」のメッセージを `stderr` に出し終了コード 0

ディレクトリ `hoge` の下にファイル `piyo` があって `cd hoge` してあるものとして

`hoge` の権限が `rwx` (ディレクトリ自体には書き込み許可)
`piyo` の権限が `r--` (ファイルは書き込み不許可)
であるとき (このとき `piyo` は削除可能)
- `rm -f piyo` は `piyo` の書き込み不許可を無視して無言で削除を行い終了コード 0
- `rm piyo || true` は確認メッセージを表示し入力待ちとなります。
　- 人の介入待ちとなってしまうのでスクリプトや `Makefile` で使うのは困難でしょう。
　- 終了コード 0 が得られることに違いはありません。

`hoge` の権限が `r-x` (ディレクトリ自体に書き込み不許可)
`piyo` の権限が `r--` (ファイルは書き込み不許可)
であるとき (このとき `piyo` は削除不可能)
- `rm -f piyo` は `piyo` の削除不能を表示し、終了コード 0 以外を返します
- `rm piyo || true` は確認メッセージを表示し入力待ちとなります。
　- 人の介入待ちとなってしまうのでスクリプトや `Makefile` で使うのは困難でしょう。
　- 削除失敗であっても終了コード 0 を返すので混乱を招くでしょう。

特に `Makefile` 中の `clean:` などに使う場合には `rm -f` のほうが断然安全です。